# what is the real benefit of using outbox pattern in an event-driven architecture

Tags: event-driven, outbox-pattern

According to all of the articles I've seen so far about the benefits of using the Outbox pattern in an event-driven architecture, they all use this pattern so if the Message Broker fails, messages don't get lost, but here's my question, aren't we worried about the time that DB fails?

I mean, what is the difference between:

- We use outbox and db fails (message gets lost!)
- We don't use outbox and Broker fails (message gets lost!)

In any case, we should be careful about our system components, unless, we may lose some data, and I don't see any valid answer that shows outbox is preventing that.

Comment: how often have you lost data due to your database failing? and how often have you lost messages due to you service / message broker failing?

Comment: @pecks To be honest, I've never experienced either in 5 years across big and small companies, maybe that's my lack of experience? 

Comment: It's useful for us. We lose messages when services get re-deployed, which is very often. Occasionally we lose them because the RabbitMQ has bounced. Our DB is pretty much never down.